# Handbrake ripped mp4 stops at 27mins 55 sec

Tags: 14.04, mp4, handbrake, disk-ripping

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit. I have installed HandBrake from add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots (thus avoiding the Debian issue) but I've found that all of the MP4's play the first 27 mins 55 secs (+/- 2 seconds) and then fail.

I've tried a number of movies and they all seem to do the same.

Is there something magic about 27 mins 55 seconds?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running out of disk space when encoding? Can your player play other video files beyond 27m55s? Did you try a different player?

Comment: Hi Bain, Nope disk space isn't an issue (I have in excess of 80Gb free and the file sizes are indicative of something much longer than 27 mins 55 secs i.e. 1.3 Gb give or take a few 100 Mbs) and I'm able to play ripped MP4s from the same media server that I created before upgrading to 14.04 and the latest snapshot build of Handbrake.

Comment: How big are the encoded files? I suspect you might be hitting the 32-bit file size limit.

Comment: The smallest file that I'm talking about is 986.3Mb and the largest (so far) is 1.5Gb. All have an .m4v extension. But I do have files of a similar size that were ripped when using Ubuntu 13.10 that do work.

Comment: I'mt interesting in reading more about this 32 bit limit. Are there articles that you could refer me to?

Comment: [2GB filesize limit](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2001/04/msg01842.html) - how big are the original video files you are trying to compress?

Comment: There is also a relevant question on StackOverflow - [2GB limit on file size when using fwrite in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730709/2gb-limit-on-file-size-when-using-fwrite-in-c)

Comment: Again, thanks Bain. Not sure how to establish the size of the files before ripping. I have however been looking at some of the files that I added to my media library while using 13.10 (all of which work) and I've got some that are as big as 2.4 Gb. These files where created using the same hardware and the same partition formatted to ext4.

Comment: If all of this worked previously with exactly the same setup then it sounds like a bug in handbrake. For details of reporting a bug check http://handbrake.fr/contribute.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the files launch and run OK on other devices I've determined that this is an issue with the Sony TV app that I'm using on my Smart T.V.